# Azure AspNetCore WebApp under high load returns "The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process"

Tags: azure, sockets, .net-core, tcp, azure-webapps

I'm hosting my AspNetCore app in Azure (Windows hosting plan P3v2 plan). It works perfectly fine under normal load (5-10 requests/sec) but under high load (100-200 requests/sec) starts to hang and requests return the following response:

```
The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.
```

And from the event logs I can get even more details:

```
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
```

I have to scale instance count to 30 instances, and while each instance getting just 3-5 requests per sec, it works just fine. I beleive that 30 hosts is too much to process this high load, beleive that the resource is underutilized and trying to find the real bottleneck. If I set instance count to 10 - everything crashes and every request starts to return the error above. Resources utilization metrics for the high load case with 30 instances enabled:

- The service plan CPU usage is low, about 10-15% for each host
- The service plan memory usage is around 30-40%
- Dependency responses quickly, 50-200 ms
- Azure SQL DTU usage is about 5%

I discovered [this useful article](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/03/01/Deep-Dive-into-TCP-Connections-in-App-Service-Diagnostics.html) on current tier limits and after an Azure TCP connections diagnostics I figured out a few possible issues:

1. High outbound TCP connection
2. High TCP Socket handle count - High TCP Socket handle count was detected on the instance .... During this period, the process dotnet.exe of site ... with ProcessId 8144 had the maximum open handle count of 17004.

So I dig more and found the following information:

[image: tcp connections state]
[image: active tcp connections]
[image: connections per instance]

Per my service plan tier, my tcp connections limit should be 8064 which is far from the displayed above. Next I've checked the socket state:

[image: socket state]

Even though I see that number of active TCP connections is below the limit, I'm wondering if open socket handles count could be an issue here. What can cause this socket handle leak (if any)? How can I troubleshoot and debug it?

Comment: HttpClient is the suspect for socket handle leak error. please see below link. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/330364/should-we-create-a-new-single-instance-of-httpclient-for-all-requests. you should use HttpClientFactory in .net core to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have tried to isolate the possible cause for the error, just highlighting some of the reasons to revalidate/remediate:

1- On Azure App Service - Connection attempts to local addresses (e.g. localhost, 127.0.0.1) and the machine's own IP will fail, except if another process in the same sandbox has created a listening socket on the destination port. Rejected connection attempts, normally returns the above socket forbidden error (above).
For peered VNet/On_premise, kindly ensure that the IP address used is in the ranges listed for routing to VNet/Incorrect routing.

2.On Azure App service -  If the outbound TCP connections on the VM instance are exhausted. [limits](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#cross-vm-numerical-limits) are enforced for the maximum number of outbound connections that can be made for each VM instance.

Other causes as highlighted in this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/10/13/investigating-socket-exception-for-asp-net-applications-in-azure-app-service/)

- Using client libraries which are not implemented to re-use TCP connections.
- Application code or the client library is leaking TCP socket handles.
- Burst load of requests opening too many TCP socket connections at once.
- In case of higher level protocol like HTTP this is encountered if the Keep-Alive option is not leveraged.

I'm unusure if you have already tried the App Service Diagonstic to fetch more details, kindly give that a shot:

Navigate to the Diagnose and solve problems blade in the Azure portal.

1. In the Azure portal, open the app in App Services.
2. Select Diagnose and solve problems > "TCP Connections"

Consider optimizing the application to implement Connection Pooling for your .Net/Observe the behavior locally. If feasible restart the WebApp and then check to see if that helps.
If the issue still persists, kindly file a support ticket for a detailed/deeper investigation of the backend logs.